# What does this mean org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:1.5.6.RELEASE -> 1.3.0.RELEASE?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

On one of my projects when I run gradle dependencies, I see

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:1.5.6.RELEASE -> 1.3.0.RELEASE
```

[image]
I want to use spring boot 1.5.6 but don't know what does this mean.

This is how the gradle is

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion}")
```

Where springBootVersion = 1.5.6.RELEASE

Comment: Please add your .gradle file as well

Comment: @MohamedAneesA - the most I can paste from the gradle file is here.

Comment: there is one plugin or one part of your build script that brings version 1.3.0.RELEASE of SpringBoot modules. you need to understand where this version comes from. It's difficult to guess if you don't provide more part of your script :  can you at least post the list of plugins you apply?

Answer (score 0):

We had a BOM in our project `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-parent:Brixton.M3`, though this has nothing to do with Spring-Boot but was controlling many dependencies in the project. We upgraded this to `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-parent:Edgware.RELEASE` but this is creating other problems for our project, but that is another thing.